# How I can set two components at same time with sharing set state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, use-state

I have two-component one is simple to search and other is advance search. I have a state `isSet` in simple search component and I want that property to share with the advance search. So that when I click the advance search button it will be pinned with my simple search component while scrolling. `isSet` is working good in a simple search and I want it to work same with another component.

Comment: Please add some code to your question, and try to specify your question more in terms of desired and current behavior

Answer (score 1):

If you need to share a state you might want to create a parent component where you define the state isPinned and pass it to both component. Also if you need to modify the state from the components you can pass a method to update it:

```
const ParentComp = () => {
    const [ isPinned, setIsPinned ] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentOne isPinned={isPinned} setIsPinned={setIsPinned} />
            <ComponentTwo isPinned={isPinned} setIsPinned={setIsPinned} />

        </div>
    )
}
```

In any of both components you can use them props like this:

```
const ComponentOne = ({ isPinned, setIsPinned }) => (
    <Button onClick={() => setIsPinned(!isPinned)} />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it as followd:-
1:- Create a class component named SwitchSearchComponent and use it in your existng component where you are calling search components 
2:- Set a state in that existing component showSearchComponent.
3:- Pass that state as prop to SwitchSearchComponent.
3:- Call both component in it conditionally with a prop value showSearchComponent.
4:- you can set showSearchComponent value simple for simple search and advance for advance serach.